# How to setup the problem $P(Z^4 - 17 \ge 9)$ for Exponential(4) distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm working on part (d) of the problem that was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841493/exponential-distribution-pz-geq-5) on Math.StackExchange.  The answer to that problem makes sense to me, and I've been able to use that answer to other, similar problems and their variations.  Part (d); however, has a different setup than I've seen before, and I was hoping someone could give me a hint or push in how to approach it.  :)

The problem is to compute $P(Z^4 - 17 \ge 9)$ for a $e^4$ distribution.  I know from the back of the book that the answer is $e^{-25}$. I'm not sure what algebraically to do to the $Z^4 - 17 \ge 9$ part of the problem in order to set up the limits on the distribution's density function integral.

For example I tried isolating $Z^4$ and taking the 4th root, but the final $e$ term's power didn't equal $-25$.

So, in short, what is the strategy to employ on these types of problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $Z$ parameterized by the mean or the rate?

Comment: The book doesn't say explicitly; however, from the previous post dealing with part (a) of this problem it appears to be parametrized by the rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you've given, the answer should indeed be
$$ P(Z \geq (26)^{1/4}) = e^{-4(26)^{1/4}}.$$
Are you sure you've read the question correctly? If so the answer in the book would be wrong.

Comment: Indeed +1. Either the question was miscopied or the answer key is incorrect.

Comment: OK, well that makes me feel a lot better.  I thought I was going nuts or just really had a gap in my understanding!  So, it looks like you isolated Z by adding 17 to both sides and then taking the fourth root.  I'll go ahead and accept the answer, and thank you for taking the time to comment on it.  :)